# Add method to be available in all Views

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, metaprogramming

I would like to have a method available to all Views in my app.

I would like to be able to make calls like this:

```
<span>${ getDynamicText() }</span>
```

The most obvious ways (to me) to implement this are:

1. Call the method in the controller and and pass it to the View.
2. Make the method static on some Util class and call it from the code `${ UtilClass.getDynamicText() }`
3. Using meta programming to somehow make the method available to all Views.

The benefit of #3 is that the change would only have to be made in one place. #1 would have to be made in each controller action; and #2 would need an import on every View page which wants to use the method.

**So is there a way to add a method to be available to all views in my app?**

I have to admit I don't know in a lot of detail how .gsp files are processed behind-the-scenes so maybe they don't have a corresponding class and therefore can't be manipulated in this way. Links to good articles/docs will get extra good karma.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks a tag library is good for this? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails03118/#N10261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSPs are compiled into classes that extend `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage`, so you can add methods to that metaclass and they'll be available to all GSPs. The best place to do this is in `BootStrap.groovy` (or in a plugin's `doWithDynamicMethods` closure):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage

class BootStrap {

   def init = { servletContext ->
      GroovyPage.metaClass.getDynamicText = { ... }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to reuse functionality across GSPs is to define it as a tag, e.g.

```
class MyTagLib {

  static namespace = 'my'

  def dynamicText = {attrs ->
    out << 'not very dynamic'
  }
}
```

You can then call this tag in a GSP using:

```
<my:dynamicText/>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is certainly a tidy solution for many situations. One limitation would be if I wanted to do something like this `<g:someTag key: "${ /* I can use metaClass property or method here, can't use a tag */ }" key2: 'b' />`. But this might suggest moving the property/method to a more appropriate place.

Comment: @David I don't understand the limitation you're referring to. Maybe you could update your question with a more detailed explanation

Comment: No, it's ok. It was a fairly contrived example, and would actually be pretty easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

4th way: make a class/service that have method '.getDynamicText' and put it's intance into request at `before` filter ( `request.setAttribute('x', myDynamicTextGeneratorObject)` )

Now you can use `x.dynamicText` in any GSP

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

- Add a new class to your controllers folder containing your method
- Do a `grails install-templates`
- Navigate to the templates: `\src\templatesscaffolding`
- Add the extends part to the controller template: `class ${className}Controller extends NewController`
- re-generate your controllers

You can now use the method in every class and gsp.

Comment: I see how this method of creating a common superclass for Controllers would work to make a method/property available to all Controllers. But how does it become available in the gsps?